# Diplomatic law and car plates

Tags: contract-law, international, constitutional-law, diplomatic-immunity, foreign-relations

What should the Ministery of Foreign Affairs of a country A do in the case in which the diplomatic car plate number is stolen in a country B? And what should the State Department do?

Answer (score 1):

For an embassy located in the US, the embassy should report the theft to the police. The [most recent diplomatic note](https://www.state.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/19-1668-New-DMV-Process-Circular-2019-12-11.pdf) just said “police report”, but [a 2009-2017 archive](https://2009-2017.state.gov/ofm/dmv/registration/lostlp/index.htm) said that this could be local police, the Secret Service, or the Bureau of Diplomatic Security. After reporting the theft to the police, the embassy sends a copy of the police report to the Office of Foreign Missions and requests replacement plates. The embassy might also have to report this to their own government.

Comment: Would they receive _different_ plates? So if ABC is stolen, the embassy receives XYZ, and now the police can freely arrest anyone driving with the ABC license plates? Otherwise there would be the ugly situation that one diplomat and one thief could be using the same plates.